# How to re-use Hibernate Criteria with Java List?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, filter, spring-data-jpa

I am using SPRING DATA JPA and its functions:

```
List<T> findAll(Specification<T> spec);     
Page<T> findAll(Specification<T> spec, Pageable pageable);
```

1- Could I reuse the Specification on a java.util.List to filter?

2- Else, if I have a java list with my filters how could I filter the list?

Kind regards!

Comment: What is Specification? Are those Spring functions?

Comment: Hi, is org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.Specification<T>